# How do I echo a string to a text file before the content that's already in?

Tags: string, batch-file, text-files, echo

I don't know if it is possible but if it is how do I, for example, `ECHO FOR /F blah blah blah >>output.txt` to the first line or before a certain line inside `output.txt` when it is not empty.

Comment: Why don't you just read the file, get the contents, then prepend the new content and then rewrite to the file.

Comment: I was just thinking if there was like a switch or something that could let you echo something to the beginning or to a specific line of a file but apparently it has to be like you proposed or the answer I was given below. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simplistic but it answers part of your question.

It adds a line at the very top of the file.

```
echo First line >newfile.txt
type oldfile.txt >>newfile.txt
move newfile.txt oldfile.txt >nul
```

Comment: This is an alternative and solves my question. This line however pauses or something `move newfile.txt oldfile.txt >nul` and does nothing. ----Edit--- Nevermind that line works but If I do `move newfile.txt oldfile.bat >nul` it doesn't, the same happens with `move newfile.bat oldfile.bat >nul`.

Comment: `move /y newfile.txt oldfile.bat >nul` <--- There is a `/Y` switch to force an overwrite without prompting. The `>nul` is there to hide the commands output and if you remove it then you can see the reason for the failure too.

Answer (score 0):

As shown [here](https://superuser.com/a/246841) you could do:

Append to first line:

```
sed -i '1s/^/blah blah blah\n/' output.txt
```

Append before a certain line `k`:

```
sed -i 'ks/^/blah blah blah\n/' output.txt
```

Comment: Yes, linux systems are a charm. Sadly I'm on windoze platform. Thanks anyways.